# Rails: dynamically naming select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, loops

I'm trying to create a series of three select boxes in a looping bit of code, thus:

```
<% for a in @issue.articles %>
  <%= f.select(:article+a.page, options_for_select([[a.name, a.id]])) %>
<% end %>
```

How would I name each select box to be `article1`, `article2`, and `article3`?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `a.page` has the number:

```
f.select "article#{a.page}" ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
f.select 'article', options, :name => 'article' + a.page.to_s, :id => '...'
```